# onPress responding to a long press only

Tags: react-native, expo

I've created an app using Expo, and when running on Android, `onPress` requires a long press to actually respond. It happens with `TouchableOpacity`, `TouchableWithoutFeedback`, `TouchableNativeFeedback` from `react-native` and `Button` from `react-native-elements`.

It doesn't matter the type of action I perform when `onPress` is triggered; my app tries to `navigate`, but even a simple `alert` requires a long press. Below is the code of one of the components I use, including its style. Many answers in SO mention about positioning and zIndex, but that doesn't seem to be my problem.

```
<TouchableOpacity
            style={{
                width: '15%',
                height: 100,
                color: 'white',
                borderTopWidth: 1,
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#333333',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                flex: 1,
                flexDirection: 'column'
            }}
            onPress={() => this.onMenuButtonClick(item)}>
            <View>
                <Icon name={item.icon} color={item.colorIcon} />
                <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

This happens only in Android, both on emulator and device. When deploying the app to iOS works fine.

Weird thing is that the back arrow for the navigation component works fine, a simple press does the work, but any of the afore mentioned components I'm using won't work when just pressed.

Any clue?

Here's an expo snack replicating the problem https://snack.expo.io/@pollirrata/cae485

Comment: Can you supply expo snack example? Also check if you have many console.log in code...

Comment: @Oleg see the snack https://snack.expo.io/@pollirrata/cae485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove TapGestureHandler, fixed snack https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/nervous-oranges

Comment: Can you elaborate on why `TapGestureHandler` is the problem?

Comment: I think that first of all that was wrong pattern with conflict of tap handling between controls.